# How to Replace a Character in a Specific Position of a String With Another Character

Tags: python

The string is `INITIAL`.

`INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~~'`

I want to replace the 4th value of `INITIAL` with a '+'. I do this:

`INITIAL.replace(INITIAL[3], '+')`

However, this replaces all of the values of INITIAL with '+'. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
initial_list = list(INITIAL)
initial_list[4] = '+'
initial_changed = "".join(initial_list)
print(initial_changed) # ~~~~+~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

its a little bit annoying, one way of doing it is `INITIAL = INITIAL[:3] + "+" + INITIAL[4:]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to address this it to assign a new value to the variable dynamically.

```py
INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
INITIAL = INITIAL[:3] + '+' + INITIAL[4:]
```

`INITIAL[:3]` refers to part of the string upto the 3rd character.
`INITIAL[4:]` refers to the 4th character and onward.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
INITIAL = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
result = ''

for i in range(len(INITIAL)):
    if i ==3: # replace the Index value here which index you want to replace.
        result = result+ '+'
    else:
        result = result+INITIAL[i]
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, 3 ways of replacing a character in a specific position of a string.

**Note:** Python strings are immutable (i.e. they can't be modified).

**Method 1:**

```
>>> text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
>>> text = list(text)  # converting string into a list
>>> text[4] = '+'
>>> text = "".join(text)
# '~~~~+~~~~~~'
```

How faster it is?

```
>>> timeit.timeit("text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'; s = list(text); s[4] = '+'; ''.join(s)", number=1000000)
0.8268570480013295
```

**Method 2:**

Using string `replace()` method

```
>>> text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
>>> text = text[:4] + (text[4:].replace(text[0], '+', 1))
```

How faster it is?

```
>>> timeit.timeit("text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'; text = text[:4] + (text[4:].replace(text[0], '+', 1))", number=1000000)
0.588400217000526
```

**Method 3:**

```
>>> text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'
>>> text = text[:4] + '+' + text[5:]
```

How faster it is?

```
>>> timeit.timeit("text = '~~~~~~~~~~~'; text = text[:4] + '+' + text[4:]", number=1000000)
0.3959887210003217
```